# Update the contents of SQL Server table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to add a single character to contents of my SQL Server table.

In the table I have a column `HighResolutionImage`. The existing content of one of the rows that column is

```
http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/coliseumimages/high_0f34869c3b5745d4.jpg
```

I want to update all the rows to have `https` in that `HighResoltionImage` column.

How do I update the content of a table in such a way that I update all the over 1000 rows affected?

I tried updating it one by one but it will take time because I have over 1000 rows to edit.

Comment: `UPDATE [yourTable] SET [yourColumn] = REPLACE([yourColumn], 'http://', 'httpS://')`

Comment: `where [yourColumn] like 'http://%'`, to keep transaction size down.

Answer (score 2):

I like [`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) for this:

```
UPDATE dbo.tableName 
  SET HighResolutionImage = STUFF(HighResolutionImage, 5, 0, 's')
  WHERE HighResolutionImage LIKE 'http://%';
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=242465363468674550df87036b123982)

While in this specific case there should only be one instance of `http://` in the string, `STUFF()` can extend to other scenarios where you only want to replace a specific instance. If you'd rather use `REPLACE()` then you can do as HoneyBadger's comment:

```
UPDATE dbo.tableName 
  SET   HighResolutionImage = REPLACE
       (HighResolutionImage, 'http://', 'https://')
  WHERE HighResolutionImage LIKE 'http://%';
```

Just keep in mind that it will replace *every* instance of `http://` so may not be the right solution in other scenarios that don't involve URLs.

Comment: That is pretty neat. I do think a `REPLACE()` is more intuitive for a simple update like this (which is likely a one time event). But I like the protection against replacing all `'http'`s  of this solution